# black screen / no events in iOS OpenGL ES 2

Tags: ios, events, opengl-es-2.0

I'm dealing with an error for about 45 days. I already tried dozens of method calls, change the whole program, but nothing works.

I use GLES 2, with a UIViewController that is the rootViewController, that has a view of type UIView, whose layerclass is CAEAGLLayer.

When i run the application, the screen gets black and if i press the screen, no events are generated.

If i rotate the application, the screen appears and the events work. Even worst, if i dont rotate the application, but put a breakpoint right after the presentRenderbuffer, and press the "Capture OpenGL ES Frame" button inside Xcode, **the screen appears and the events start working**!!!

What i feel is that the view is not actually shown, however, i implemented the viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, loadView (where i start everything), all these methods gets called in this order:

load view
view will appear
view will layout subviews
view did appear

Also, the view has actually a valid frame size.

Any help is greatly appreciated for this desperate user.

guich

Comment: does `presentRenderbuffer` return true? and can you show your rendering code?

Comment: yes, returns true. the code is very complex, because it is a virtual machine. the view/controller is initialized in one thread, and the gl context is initialized in another thread. for me, the most curious is what happens with the "Capture frame" button: once i press that button, my render buffer shows up on screen without any line of code of my program being called (i know it because the program is paused due to the breakpoint)! seems like that this button does a flush in something. already tried glFlush with no success

Comment: I'd suggest running all UIKit and OpenGL code on main thread, that's what I do and my iOS OpenGL ES app works. Apple said that all UIKit classes should be used on main thread (ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html) however I am not sure if OpenGL code is required to run on main thread or not.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not an option for me. The UI runs in a thread, and i have an event loop that runs in another thread. Its impossible to use the same thread. This approach works nicely for Android. Also, at some very rare moments, when i run the application, the screen gets shown correctly at start. But i don't get this situation since at least 30 days ago. Have a great 2013!

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem was: setup the context in the main thread, where all windows are created, and then share the open gl context between all threads by calling

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:glcontext]
```

at each thread