# iOS EAGL video rendering only works after device rotation

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an application that draws video frames to a UIView with a CAEAGLLayer class layer. The video frames are generated/decoded using GStreamer.

I'm a newbie in the OpenGL(ES) world, the issue I'm facing is that I get no errors from glGetError, but the video isn't being shown until I rotate the iPad then it works and I can rotate it back to the original orientation and it keeps working. The same behaviour happens with the simulator.

It also works after using the XCode GL debugging features (that shows the GL buffers and objects), after activating it and letting the program run again, the video is rendered nicely.

What could be the reason for this? Any GL command that rotating the device or enabling the GL debugging could be running that I might be missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074511/black-screen-no-events-in-ios-opengl-es-2?rq=1 This answers my question. I'll post as a real answer once I can (need to wait 6 hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[black screen / no events in iOS OpenGL ES 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074511/black-screen-no-events-in-ios-opengl-es-2?rq=1)

This question had the same issue as mine, and the same solution worked.

Great!